# How is stack-allocated data in the "middle" of the stack accessed?

Tags: stack

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
x = 10
y = 20

print(x)
print(y)
```

For the sake of argument, let's say that x and y are allocated to the stack in the order they appear. That is, our stack looks something like this:

```
y: [20] <- stack pointer
x: [10]
   ---- <- stack origin
```

In order to print (i.e. access) `x`, we first need to pop `y` off the stack, peek at `x`, and then push `y` back on. In between popping and pushing `y`, its value needs to be temporarily stored somewhere other than the stack. We can't simply discard `y`, since we need to print it later.

More generally, if we want to access a value that's N bytes below the stack pointer, we need to temporarily store those top N bytes somewhere in case they need to be accessed later.

My question is, how is this done in practice? While we are accessing a value in the middle of the stack, where is all the data on top stored?

Comment: What do you mean with _in practice_? For example, the Intel CPUs (x86 architecture) allow to address with an offset relative to the address in the SP (Stack Pointer) register. Additionally, there is a BP (Base Pointer) register. It's usual to back the SP into the BP before pushing local variables onto the stack. Thus, the BP reflects a specific intermediate state of the stack and can be used to address function arguments and local variables (again with offsets relative to the address in the BP).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat By "in practice" I mean, how would a variable allocated like `x` be accessed from a real program's stack? Is it done the way I described in the question (pop data above `x`, then push it back on), or can the middle of the stack be addressed directly? From what you said about SP offsets, it seems like the latter is the case. In other words, the LIFO push/pull restriction only applies to allocation, not access. Would that be a correct interpretation?

Comment: There are distinct CPU architectures. AFAIK, Suns SPARC CPUs provide(d) a larger number of registers. Hence, in the usual case for C/C++ function calls, the arguments are handed over in registers. Even for Intel CPUs, registers are used in specific cases for arguments (instead of the stack).

Comment: What I intended to tell you: There is not _one practice_. A stack is only one option, and there are possibly others. However, _if_ stack is used I guess it always can be combined with the option of random addressing (relative or absolute). Otherwise, I could imagine that such a platform would be rather useless (concerning performance etc.) I even can imagine that a stack can be organized in S/W as well - without explicit H/W support in the CPU i.e. if there aren't dedicated registers like SP and BP in Intels x86 arch.